# What's the maximum reputation for a user

Tags: discussion

I have take a look at [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s info page, and found that his current reputation is 538k. And now I have a question, **what is the maximum reputation for a user**? Is it 1000k or *unlimited*?

Comment: Depends on what the datatype they use is.

Comment: It's an ever increasing maximum as defined by Jon Skeet. Simple as that.

Comment: I suspect `2147483647`.

Comment: August 28, 2016 we'll know whether there is a 1000k limit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This depends entirely on the datatype used for the total reputation column in the database. The Stack Exchange [software stack](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network) is based on Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (although it [started out on MS SQL Server 2008](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/)).

MS SQL Server has [several integer types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx); if the column is of type `int`, then the limit is 2,147,483,647 (2 billion plus change). And the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer filtered copy of the site data](https://data.stackexchange.com/) uses `int` for reputation, making it *very* likely that the production database uses the same type.

Edit: Nick Craver [confirmed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169623/whats-the-maximum-reputation-for-a-user/169626#comment500860_169626) `int` is used. That means we have another 2000 years to go before Jon Skeet's reputation forces a database upgrade to `bigint`.

Comment: It would be more effective to use the unsigned version, as there cannot be a negative reputation. So 4 billion plus change it is :)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: I don't *see* an unsigned version of the `int` type.

Comment: A database without an unsigned version of a number column? Yeah, I see why I don't use it :P

Comment: According to http://data.stackexchange.com/, `Reputation` is an `int`. So this is correct.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff: Since the SEDE is a filtered copy of the database, we cannot be 100% certain that the production database uses the same type, but it certainly would make sense if it did. :-)

Comment: This is correct

Answer (score 1):

There are several types of numbers in a database (all unsigned, because there can't be a negative reputation):

- TINYINT - 0-255. Obviously not.
- SMALLINT - 0-65535. Obviously not.
- MEDIUMINT - 0-16777215. Possible, though I don't know.
- INT - 0-4294967295. Possible, that's probably it.
- BIGINT - 0-18446744073709551615. Overkill, but who knows, based on Jon Skeet that may be the case.

I don't know exactly which Stack Exchange uses, but if anything, it's MEDIUMINT and above.

Answer (score 1):

Jon Skeet has an average of **333.90...** points per day.

538 283 (JonSkeetRep) / 53 (MonthsActive) * (365 / 12) (avgDaysPerMonth)

2^32 = 4294967296 (unsigned int)

4294967296 / 333.90 (JonSkeetDailyRepAvg) = 12863034.7289... (NumberOfDaysToOverflow)

12863034.7289 (NumberOfDaysToOverflow) / 365.25 (AvgDaysInYear) = 35217.069757... (NumberOfYearsToOverflow)

So Jon Skeet would still have to live **another** 35217 years.

Comment: I think my average rep per day is now more like 338 than 280.

Comment: The reputation cap still works on Jon Skeet. He cannot earn more than 200 rep/day, and his reputation cannot expand past that daily (he still gets votes/accepts though, but still a 200 rep limit is a 200 rep limit)

Comment: @Grammar: the reputation cap doesn't apply to accepts.

Comment: @Grammar: It also doesn't apply to bounties.